# Is there some view of question history that can help explain (to myself!) why I answered this question?

Tags: discussion, revision-history

About 4 years ago I submitted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61916381/9117) to a question.  It got upvoted recently so I took a look at it.  I was really surprised to see that my answer was posted more than a year *after* the highest-voted answer, and that *my answer is almost identical to that answer*.  It really adds nothing to the existing answer. (The fact that they are so similar can be explained by both of the answers being based off of code in the question.)

It made me wonder why on Earth I posted this answer at all.  I don't just duplicate answers to try to gain rep. (My posting this question here should, I hope, make that clear.) I can't see why I didn't see and just upvote the answer already there.

My question is: Could there have been some explanation for this in the history of the questions and answer? For example, did I answer the question and then this older answer was  moved from some other duplicate question? Or could there have been some reason that that answer would not have been visible at the time I wrote my answer?

I'm just genuinely mystified.  I can accept that I was just being clueless and unobservant that day, but I'd like to think that there was some other explanation.

Comment: All posts have a [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61916381/timeline), I can't see anything about a merge in there (I'll intentionally find a merged post to check what it shows shortly).

Comment: Yep, merges do show up in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74213400/timeline)

Comment: @ThomA Thanks for checking that.  Now that I know where it is I can do that myself.

Comment: @toolic Good catch.  It was the highest-voted, not the accepted, answer.

Comment: Looks like a good opportunity to get the [Disciplined](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) badge

Comment: @Nick I've deleted the answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the "clock" icon under the voting/save icons on the question to get to the timeline. Merged posts have a special history event ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/492558/timeline)).

In your case, nothing special is shown by any timeline (e.g., no edits on the answer timelines), so only you can explain why you chose to post that answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the clock. I was hovering over various links and fields trying to find something like the revision history.